# Ensuring SAMLSecurityToken was not intercepted

Tags: wcf, validation, security, saml

I have a WCF service in which I issue a SAMLSecurityToken to an external client for authentication.

I need to make sure that the token was not intercepted by a third party when it comes back and is attempted to be used for service calls. Any suggestions on how to do this type of validation?

I'm currently doing the following validation on the token already:

- Validating token is not expired
- Validating token was signed by our server certificate

Comment: So you're acting as both the IdP and the SP?

Comment: Currently yes. We may move the IDP functionality to a different server away from the normal service calls. Even if the Identity provider were on a separate box the question still remains: How do I ensure the client using the token was issued that token?  Need to make sure a 3rd party didn't intercept that token.

I know there are properties on the SAML token where I can put some of the clients unique identifiers (IP address, certificate thumbprint, etc).  I can parse out the token and make sure they match the client making the call.  Wondering if there is a more correct way of doing it.

Comment: Perhaps Holder-of-key token is what you need? http://dulanja.blogspot.com/2013/01/saml-subject-confirmation-methods.html